# Iterator hasNext for the last record fetching

Tags: java, iterator

```
private static void printList(LinkedList<String> linkedList) 
{
        Iterator<String> i = linkedList.iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()) 
        {
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }

        System.out.println("-------------------");
}
```

As per my understanding, `i.hasNext()` method checks whether the next entry exists or not and returns true or false.

And the `i.next()` method above here, will display the current linkedList record and then increments/moves to the next record.

If we are in the last record, `i.hasNext()` is false, how is it still executing the last iteration of `i.next()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend you check out how the `next` and `hasNext` methods are implemented in the OpenJDK: [Link](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#L875).

The linked list iterator has an `nextIndex` variable that points to the index of the item that should be returned if you call `next`. Calling `next`, as you has identified, will increment this variable.

Let's say you have the list `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, and you are about to call `next()` for the third time. After that, the state of the iterator looks like:

```
            nextIndex is pointing to this
               |
               V
0    1    2    3    4
          ^
          |
        return value of the third next()
```

I think you have this confusion because you don't understand what `hasNext` is doing. `hasNext` does not check whether whether the index *after* `nextIndex` is a valid index. It checks whether `nextIndex` is a valid index. This is how `hasNext` is implemented:

```
return nextIndex < size;
```

As long as `hasNext` is pointing to an item in the list, that is true.

Now let's see what happens in the next iteration of the loop:

```
                 nextIndex is pointing to this
                    |
                    V
0    1    2    3    4
               ^
               |
             return value of the fourth next()
```

`nextIndex` is `4` (not to be confused with the element that it points to), which is less than `size` (5), so `hasNext` is still true, so you the loop gets to run one more time:

```
                      nextIndex is pointing to this
                         |
                         V
0    1    2    3    4
                    ^
                    |
                  return value of the fifth next()
```

Now `nextIndex` is greater than `size`, pointing to something outside of the linked list, so `hasNext` is false, and the loop stops. `next` has returned all 5 elements.

Comment: Hi Thank you for answering this question, from the answers what i can depict is that, even though the name is hasNext(), its just checking hasCurrent() -> If i map my mind in this way, i can write code as i need correct?

Comment: @ShrihariKulkarni it depends on what you mean by “next” and “current”. “Next” in `hasNext` refers to the next element that hasn’t been returned yet, which is also what `nextIndex` is pointing to *currently*.

Answer (score 3):

So say you have your list as `1, 2, 3, 4`

Your iterator `hasNext()` will return `true` when it will start since it's currently pointing to the start and next has `1` in it. With `i.next()`, you will get `1`.

Now, in second to last iteration, when the cursor is at 3 and you have received `3` with `i.next()`. Now `i.hasNext()` will return `true` since it has `4` and you will be inside the loop, doing `i.next()` that consumes the whole list so next invocation of `i.hasNext()` will return `false`, terminating the loop.

[image]

Comment: In the first iteration, does hasNext function check whether 1 exists or not ? or it checks whether 2 exists or not ? 

If it checks for 1 exists or not, then i have got the clear answer, but the name should have been hasCurrent in that case.

Comment: @ShrihariKulkarni In 1st iteration it checks if 1 exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

e.g., list as 1, 2, 3, 4

See the java.util.LinkedList.ListItr.java

```
public boolean hasNext() {
  return nextIndex < size;
}
```

1. 

nextIndex = 0, size = 4, hence hasNext = true, then if you you call next() then it returns item from position 0 that is = 1 and increment nextIndex + 1

2.
nextIndex = 1, size = 4, hence hasNext = true, then if you you call next() then it returns item from position 1 that is = 2 and increment nextIndex + 1

3.
nextIndex = 2, size = 4, hence hasNext = true, then if you you call next() then it returns item from position 2 that is = 3 and increment nextIndex + 1

4.
nextIndex = 3, size = 4, hence hasNext = true, then if you you call next() then it returns item from position 3 that is = 4 and increment nextIndex + 1

5.
nextIndex = 4, size = 4, hence hasNext = **FALSE**

Answer (score 1):

Iterator is a Interface. Here is code how hasNext() and next() method works.

```
// Java code to illustrate the use of iterator 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        list.add("A"); 
        list.add("B"); 
        list.add("C"); 
        list.add("D"); 
        list.add("E"); 

        // Iterator to traverse the list 
        Iterator iterator = list.iterator(); 

        System.out.println("List elements : "); 

        while (iterator.hasNext()) 
        {
          
          System.out.print(iterator.hasNext()+" "+iterator.next() + " "+iterator.hasNext()+"\n"); 
        }
        System.out.println(); 
    } 
}
```

output of above code:
List elements :
true A true
true B true
true C true
true D true
true E false

Defination of hasNext() and next() methods:

```
public class NextFromIterator implements Iterator<String> {
    private int position = -1;
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("alpha"); add("bravo"); add("charlie"); add("delta"); add("echo"); add("foxtrot");
    }};
     
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return next() != null;  // BAD: Call to 'next'
    }
     
    public String next() {
        position++;
        return position < list.size() ? list.get(position) : null;
    }
 
    public void remove() {
        // ...
    }
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NextFromIterator x = new NextFromIterator();
        while(x.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(x.next());
        }
    }
```

Every Iteration next() increment the its pointer by 1 initial it is point to -1. After that pointer is checked with actual size of iterator if it is less than that then this method returns that element otherwise it returns null. In hasNext() method this next() method called for every loop and here it is checked that weather it is equal to null or not.